# Spring boot (Netflix) Eureka replicas

Tags: spring, spring-boot, registry, microservices, netflix-eureka

I can't configure Eureka with a replica. I have two instances of Eureka Server running on the same laptop. It always see each other as **unavailable-replica**.

The is what the Eureka panel says:
[Eureka message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsJFJ.png)

These are the application.yml  files:

```
------------------------------
server:
    port: 8761

eureka:   
    instance:
        hostname: eurekaserver1
    client:
       registerWithEureka: false
       fetchRegistry: false
       serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka

--------------------------------

server:
    port: 8762

eureka:
    instance:
       hostname: eurekaserver2
    client:
       registerWithEureka: false
       fetchRegistry: false
       serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different hostnames and the same application name(appname). Here is a detailed guide on [Eureka's peer awareness.](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2018/03/18/spring-boot-service-discovery-eureka/)

Comment: Already tried that, still doesn't work. Thanks for your help either way

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following config and it works fine, I think it does not work since you have set `registerWithEureka` and `fetchRegistry` to `false`.

### **Node.1:**

```
server:
    port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    appname: discovery-cluster
    hostname: discovery-node1
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.replicas.node.host}:${eureka.replicas.node.port}/eureka/
  replicas:
    node:
      host: ${node2.ip}
      port: 8762
```

---

### **Node.2:**

```
server:
    port: 8762

eureka:
  instance:
    appname: discovery-cluster
    hostname: discovery-node2
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.replicas.node.host}:${eureka.replicas.node.port}/eureka/
  replicas:
    node:
      host: ${node1.ip}
      port: 8761
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the combination of both @indika and @Ashraf answers that will make it work:

1. You need to use hostnames, for example adding `X.X.X.X peer1 peer2` on your *\etc\hosts* file, where `X.X.X.X` needs to be your laptop's IP address, **not 127.0.0.1**.
2. You need to remove `registerWithEureka: false` from your *application.yml* file. The Eureka servers have to register themselves with each other.

Following the documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#spring-cloud-eureka-server-peer-awareness) and adding the two alias `peer1` and `peer2` on my */etc/hosts*, I managed to configure two Eureka servers on my laptop with valid *available-replicas* using the *application.yml* below:

```
---
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  profiles: peer1
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer2:8082/eureka/

---
server:
  port: 8082
spring:
  profiles: peer2
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer1:8081/eureka/
```

You can run both instances using the two different profiles as follows:

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=peer1 build/libs/registry.jar
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=peer2 build/libs/registry.jar
```